# the following expects a variable to be passed:

Tags: php

```
$img= mysql_real_escape_string(end(explode('/',$_POST['img'])));
```

the statement expects a variable to be passed, any idea on how to use both the end and explode functions?

Comment: `$foo = end(explode(...)); $bar = m_r_e_s($foo)`?

Comment: while the cool kids nest like this, its so much esier to debug if you dont

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Have you tried searching Google to find out how to use them? Or perhaps the PHP documentation?

Answer (score 0):

`the statement expects a variable to be passed` so why don't you pass it a variable reference to the `end` function ?

```
$images = explode('/',$_POST['img']);
$lastImage = end($images);
$img = mysql_real_escape_string($lastImage);
```